# Flask: how to login/logout with fetch API?

Tags: python, flask, fetch-api, flask-login

I have the following routes for logging in/out and checking logging status:

```
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user

@app.route('/check_login_status')
def check_login_status():
    return str(current_user.is_authenticated)
    
@app.route('/log_in')
def log_in():
    user = User.query.first()
    login_user(user)
    return 'OK'
    
@app.route('/log_out')
def log_out():
    logout_user()
    return 'OK'
```

If I enter those routes manually in the browser, everything works as expected - the user gets logged in/out and `check_login_status` returns correct boolean value.

However, I need to access those routes with `fetch` API on the frontend like this:

```
function login() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/log_in')
}
            
function logout() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/log_in')
}
```

But calling those functions in the frontend (upon button click for example) will not affect the login status: the response of `check_login_status` route will remain unchanged.

Why is that so and can I fix this?

Comment: You can read fetch API in this link ```https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch```

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your login route

```
@app.route('/log_in')
def log_in():
user = User.query.first() // this is wrong .. you always login 
                          //with the first user in your database table 
login_user(user)
return 'OK'
```

.....
so first you need to specify the method for this route to be posted

```
@app.route('/log_in' , methods=['POST'])
```

and you receive the user credentials in the request body for example email and password

```
user_data= request.get_json()
```

then query by email

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email=user_dat['email']).first()
```

then you need to hash the password coming in the request and compare it to the hashed password of the user saved in the database .. if they are identical
then pass it to your login_user function
login_user(user)

/// java script
in request you need to do it like that

```
function login() {
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/log_in',{
method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({email:'email@email.com',password:'password'}),}).then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).catch((err) => {
  return err;
});
```

}